# Run Atom as different user on Ubuntu

Tags: atom-editor, xfce

I have been trying to make Atom run as a different user than the one currently logged in. I am not talking about sudo privileges - just a different ordinary user.

I get this rather cryptic error:

```
/usr/bin/atom: line 190: 1796547 Aborted (core dumped) nohup "$ATOM_PATH" >--executed-from="$(pwd)" --pid=$$ "$@" > "$ATOM_HOME/nohup.out" 2>&1
No protocol specified
The futex facility returned an unexpected error code.
```

Ubuntu: 20.04.2 LTS

Xfce: 4.14

I have tried messing around with user groups, but it seems to be something else. Possibly a problem with the desktop?
Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Best regards
Jonas

Comment: What command did you run that gave that error?

Comment: First I did "su newUser" and then just "atom"

Comment: Are those environment variables defined? Check with `declare -p ATOM_PATH ATOM_HOME`

Comment: They are not. Says "not found" for both of them. But I just checked with my primary user (for which Atom does work) and they are not declared there either.

Comment: Oh, actually, they're not environment variables, they're defined within the script. It's confusing that they're uppercase.

Comment: BTW, the `>` shouldn't be there in `... >--executed-from=...`

Comment: No idea :) But as I said it works fine with the primary user, so I'm thinking the problem has something to do with the user change. Perhaps because the desktop is running under the other user?

Comment: You could try `DISPLAY=:0 atom`, although I'm not sure if it's relevant